# Is there a way to use a custom JUnit Test Runner when running tests in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit, jmockit

I want to use [JMockit](http://jmockit.dev.java.net)'s incremental test runner instead of the standard JUnit test runners from within Eclipse. Is there a way to do this?

**Edit** Received the following answer to my email to the JMockit dev:

> You would need to start the JVM with a
>   command line such as
>   "-javaagent:jmockit.jar=incjunit4",
>   where "incjunit4" specifies that the
>   external tool for incremental JUnit
>   tests be loaded. The coverage tool
>   must also be used, because it provides
>   the necessary runtime information to
>   the incremental test tool. In fact,
>   there is no documentation about that,
>   mainly because this feature is not
>   fully developed yet.

Unfortunately this still doesn't work for me. Has anyone gotten the incremental test runner to work?

Answer (score 1):

it has worked for me, you need to run test normal way, than go to Run and properties of that Test and enter value with jmockit patch(path to jar)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the `@RunWith` annotation?